# node object module return object

Tags: object, module, undefined

Is it possible to return a Node object from a file to another?

ex:

**file_1**

```
myObject = function(x){
    this.x = x
    this.change = function(){
        return myObject("new_value");
    }
}
module.exports = myObject;
```

**file_2**

```
F1 = require('file_2');
f1 = new F1("some_value");
new = f1.change();
```

On my code, *new* now has "undefined". Is there a way to return the new object?

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: I'm using Javascript.

Comment: Just found the answer. Silly me: I was not returning __"new myObject"__

Answer (score 0):

file_1 should be:

```
myObject = function(x){
    this.x = x
    this.change = function(){
        return myObject("new_value");
    }
}
module.exports = myObject;
```

Comment: Oh, i forgot it in here, but in my code it does have it.